# Fluent Nhibernate mapping to different columns by condition

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, firebird

I have an a date table what contains some columns:
INTEGER_VALUE, DOUBLE_VALUE, STRING_VALUE, DATETIME_VALUE

An object is:

```
public class Property
{
    public virtual int Id { set; get; }
    public virtual PropertyKind Kind { set; get; }
    public virtual object Value { set; get; }
    public PropertyValueType ValueType { set; get; }
}
```

`PropertyValueType` is:

```
public enum PropertyValueType
{
    TypeInt,
    TypeString,
    TypeDouble,
    TypeDateTime
}
```

The target is to map `Value` to different column of Database (firebird) condition to ValueType. For example if `ValueType` is `TypeString` we need to map it to STRING_VALUE column etc. `ValueType` sets while object begin created (in constructor) and never be changed.
Is it possible? Or may be another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate could help us to map Tables into C# objects / entities *([ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping))*. That means:

> we should properly map ALL table's columns into ALL C# entity properties.

Later *(e.g. business layer or inside of the `get` and `set`)* we should apply some validation rules to achieve required behaviour. Also we should extend the application tier to assure that for each kind of enum `PropertyValueType`, correct *Property* is filled, and will be persisted in a proper *Column.*

So the object structure could be like this

```
public class Property
{
    public virtual int Id { set; get; }
    public virtual PropertyKind Kind { set; get; }
    public PropertyValueType ValueType { set; get; }

    // not mapped
    public virtual object Value { ... some logic inside of the getter and setter }


    // mapped properties - could be protected and hidden from upper consumers
    protected virtual int?      IntValue      { get; set;}
    protected virtual string    StringValue   { get; set;}
    protected virtual double?   DoubleValue   { get; set;}
    protected virtual DateTime? DateTimeValue { get; set;}
}
```

So, NHibernate will help us to mapp columns and properties 1:1. The remaining handling is up to our application.

*At the end this will bring us a lot, because we can issue even `OrderBy` accross all rows, while only some of them do have the column filled...*

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy NHibernate, great tool ;)